# Updating Android on a Rooted Tablet

Tags: updates, root-access

I have an Android tablet that I rooted to attempt to install a different OS. After I failed and restored my tablet to a backup that I had made earlier (it's still rooted), I tried to update Android. It checked for updates, and promptly displayed a box that said "Your device has been modified. Software updates are not available." Is there any way that I can update my tablet while it's rooted?

Comment: It might help if we knew a bit more information about your tablet. Who is the manufacturer? What Android version is it running?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just installing CyanogenMod. They have features that stock Android should have had from the beginning, and support pretty much every Android device on the market for many years after Google and the various device manufacturers abandon it.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the steps necessary to use this? My Samsung tablet apparently has a Knox "warranty" flag which is an eFuse and cannot be reset. From what I have read I am uncertain if the device can even be modified, especially if the bootloader is involved.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods for updating your device. Once you've rooted it, the checksum for your `/system` partition changes, and an update might check that and abort because of it (as you just experienced); this is mostly the case with [ota-update](/questions/tagged/ota-update)s.

However: major version updates are rarely spread OTA, but mostly have to be flashed manually using a corresponding computer program. Which one that might be, is manufacturer-specific and depends on your device (so for details on that, we need to know which one it is). Still, applied as an update it might again fail with its checksum verification.

A third variant would be assuming a "virgin device", and make a full install. This usually does not apply any checksum verification (as it does a complete install, and not an update). For this, you might want to check with [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

More details on device updates can be found checking [frequent questions tagged "update"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update?sort=frequent) and our [update tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/update/info).

P.S.: After clarification for the targeted device, there are two more tags you might want to investigate: [odin](/questions/tagged/odin) is Samsung's flash-tool for Windows, [heimdall](/questions/tagged/heimdall) is a multi-platform open source equivalent.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this in my question; it's a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (p3113), running Android 4.2.2

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I've just updated my answer accordingly with links to the Samsung tools involved in ROM flashing. You can take a look at their tag-wikis for more details (and consider accepting the answer by tapping the checkmark next to it, if it answered your question sufficiently).

Comment: I originally used odin to root the tablet, and then installed ClockWork Mod Recovery. Is there a way that I can update Android but keep my settings and apps, like it would do if I updated it from the settings pane the normal way?

Comment: That always depends, and you never can be 100% sure. Details I must leave to those used to Sammy's devices and tools – but it never hurts to have a good backup. Take a look at our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for good hints on that. In short, *Titanium Backup* and `adb backup` (including the *Helium* frontend) can be your good friends with that.